# Best Sleep quality index: polysomnography (PSG) , The Pittsburgh Sleep Quality Index (PSQI) or

Tags: sleep

I am interested in sleep quality measuring and by seeing [this](https://sci-hub.tw/10.1109/ICHI.2014.24) paper:

**Towards Benchmarked Sleep Detection with Inertial Wrist-worn Sensing Units**

I have seen this part paper:

[image]

So i like to know which one could better estimate sleep quality ;  [polysomnography (PSG)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polysomnography) indexing or [Pittsburgh Sleep Quality Index (PSQI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pittsburgh_Sleep_Quality_Index) or any more completed index ( which i don't know now!)?

**Update:**

Maybe based of [this](https://sci-hub.tw/10.1007/s00779-017-1038-9) paper part diary are better indexing?:

[image]

Thanks